# Oracle View has been found to be inefficient and using TB of memory

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have a view that has been amended over recent months that now according to explain queries is consuming TB of memory. The view looks like this...

```
DROP VIEW KLL_DTL_VIEW;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW KLL_DTL_VIEW
(PLACENAME, PLACESTATUS, PLACEPLC, PLACERECOVERING, PLACEADDRESS, 
CENTERNAME, CENTERLOCATION, CENTERORDER, CENTERLINE, CENTERITEM, 
CENTERQUANTITY, CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY, CENTERERRORQUANTITY, CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY, 
CENTERSTATUS, 
CENTERPLCORDER, CENTERPLCERRORCODES, CENTERLOCKS, CENTERINVLOCKS, CENTERINVLINE, 
TGTNAME, TGTLOCATION, TGTORDER, TGTCARTON, TGTQUANTITY, 
TGTLOCKS)
BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS 
WITH
    ROV_STATION
    AS
        (SELECT S.NAME                   PLACENAME,
                SA.ROVSTATUS             PLACESTATUS,
                SA.PLC                   PLACEPLC,
                SA.ROBOTRECOVERING       PLACERECOVERING,
                P.ADDRESS                PLACEADDRESS,
                NULL                     CENTERNAME,
                NULL                     CENTERLOCATION,
                NULL                     CENTERORDER,
                NULL                     CENTERLINE,
                NULL                     CENTERITEM
           FROM STATION  S
                JOIN STATION_ATTRIBUTES SA ON S.ID = SA.ENTITY_ID
                JOIN STORAGE_ROLE SR ON S.PLACE_ROLE_ID = SR.ID
                JOIN PLACE P ON SR.PLACE_ID = P.ID
          WHERE S.NAME = 'ROV08'),
    ROV_LDS
    AS
        (SELECT LC.ID                            ID,
                LC.NAME                          NAME,
                LISTAGG (DISTINCT EL.REASON, '|')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EL.REASON)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY LC.ID)    LOCKS,
                CASE
                    WHEN SP.NAME = 'TS01'
                    THEN
                        NVL2 (DLCTS.PLACE_ID,
                              'Transporting To ' || DP.NAME,
                              '')
                    ELSE
                           NVL2 (SLCTS.PLACE_ID || DLCTS.PLACE_ID,
                                 'Transporting From ' || SP.NAME,
                                 SP.NAME)
                        || NVL2 (DLCTS.PLACE_ID, ' To ' || DP.NAME, '')
                END                              LOCATION
           FROM LD  LC
                LEFT JOIN
                (  SELECT MIN (TRANSPORT_STATUS)     TRANSPORT_STATUS,
                          LD_ID
                     FROM LD_TRANSPORT_STATUS
                    WHERE TRANSPORT_STATUS < 1
                 GROUP BY LD_ID) MSLCTS
                    ON MSLCTS.LD_ID = LC.ID
                LEFT JOIN LD_TRANSPORT_STATUS SLCTS
                    ON     SLCTS.LD_ID = MSLCTS.LD_ID
                       AND SLCTS.TRANSPORT_STATUS =
                           MSLCTS.TRANSPORT_STATUS
                LEFT JOIN PLACE SP
                    ON SP.ID =
                       CASE
                           WHEN SLCTS.PLACE_ID IS NOT NULL
                           THEN
                               SLCTS.PLACE_ID
                           ELSE
                               LC.PLACE_ID
                       END
                LEFT JOIN
                (  SELECT MAX (TRANSPORT_STATUS)     TRANSPORT_STATUS,
                          LD_ID
                     FROM LD_TRANSPORT_STATUS
                    WHERE TRANSPORT_STATUS >= 1
                 GROUP BY LD_ID) MDLCTS
                    ON MDLCTS.LD_ID = LC.ID
                LEFT JOIN LD_TRANSPORT_STATUS DLCTS
                    ON     DLCTS.LD_ID = MDLCTS.LD_ID
                       AND DLCTS.TRANSPORT_STATUS =
                           MDLCTS.TRANSPORT_STATUS
                LEFT JOIN PLACE DP ON DP.ID = DLCTS.PLACE_ID
                JOIN ROV_STATION RS
                    ON    SP.ADDRESS LIKE
                              '%' || RS.PLACENAME || '%'
                       OR DP.ADDRESS LIKE
                              '%' || RS.PLACENAME || '%'
                LEFT JOIN ENTITY_LOCK EL ON EL.LD_ID = LC.ID),
    ROV_CENTER_LDS
    AS
        (SELECT NULL
                    PLACENAME,
                NULL
                    PLACESTATUS,
                NULL
                    PLACEPLC,
                NULL
                    PLACERECOVERING,
                NULL
                    PLACEADDRESS,
                RLC.NAME
                    CENTERNAME,
                RLC.LOCATION
                    CENTERLOCATION,
                O.NAME
                    CENTERORDER,
                OL.NAME
                    CENTERLINE,
                OOLA.ITEMFORMAT
                    CENTERITEM,
                NVL (ILR.QUANTITY, 0)
                    CENTERQUANTITY,
                NVL (RPS.ORIGINAL_QUANTITY, 0)
                    CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY,
                NVL (OOLA.RVERRORPKQUANTITY, 0)
                    CENTERERRORQUANTITY,
                NVL (OOLA.COMPLETEQUANTITY, 0)
                    CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY,
                NVL (RPS.ROBOT_PK_STATUS_ID, 0)
                    CENTERSTATUS,
                RPS.ROBOT_ORDER_ID
                    CENTERPLCORDER,
                RPS.ERROR_CODES
                    CENTERPLCERRORCODES,
                RLC.LOCKS
                    CENTERLOCKS,
                LISTAGG (DISTINCT EL.REASON, '|')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EL.REASON)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY IL.ID)
                    CENTERINVLOCKS,
                IL.ID
                    CENTERINVLINE,
                NULL
                    TGTNAME,
                NULL
                    TGTLOCATION,
                NULL
                    TGTORDER,
                NULL
                    TGTCARTON,
                NULL
                    TGTQUANTITY,
                NULL
                    TGTLOCKS
           FROM ROV_LDS  RLC
                JOIN SECTION S ON S.LD_ID = RLC.ID
                JOIN INV_LINE IL ON IL.SECTION_ID = S.ID
                JOIN INV_LINE_RESERVATION ILR
                    ON ILR.INV_LINE_ID = IL.ID
                JOIN ORDER_LINE OL ON OL.ID = ILR.ORDER_LINE_ID
                JOIN OUTBOUNDORDERLINE_ATTRIBUTES OOLA
                    ON OOLA.ENTITY_ID = OL.ID
                JOIN ORDERS O ON O.ID = OL.ORDER_ID
                LEFT JOIN RESERVATION_PK_STATUS RPS
                    ON RPS.INV_LINE_RESERVATION_ID = ILR.ID
                LEFT JOIN ENTITY_LOCK EL ON EL.INV_LINE_ID = IL.ID),
    ROV_TGT_LDS
    AS
        (  SELECT NULL                           PLACENAME,
                  NULL                           PLACESTATUS,
                  NULL                           PLACEPLC,
                  NULL                           PLACERECOVERING,
                  NULL                           PLACEADDRESS,
                  NULL                           CENTERNAME,
                  NULL                           CENTERLOCATION,
                  NULL                           CENTERORDER,
                  NULL                           CENTERLINE,
                  NULL                           CENTERITEM,
                  NULL                           CENTERQUANTITY,
                  NULL                           CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY,
                  NULL                           CENTERERRORQUANTITY,
                  NULL                           CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY
             FROM ROV_LDS RLC
                  JOIN OUTBOUNDORDER_ATTRIBUTES OOA
                      ON OOA.TGT = RLC.NAME
                  JOIN ORDERS O ON O.ID = OOA.ENTITY_ID
                  LEFT JOIN SECTION S ON S.LD_ID = RLC.ID
                  LEFT JOIN INV_LINE IL ON IL.SECTION_ID = S.ID
         GROUP BY RLC.NAME,
                  RLC.LOCATION,
                  O.NAME,
                  OOA.CARTONNAME,
                  RLC.LOCKS),
    RV_UNKNOWN_CENTER_LDS
    AS
        (SELECT NULL             PLACENAME,
                NULL             PLACESTATUS,
                NULL             PLACEPLC,
                NULL             PLACERECOVERING,
                NULL             PLACEADDRESS,
                RLC.NAME         CENTERNAME,
                RLC.LOCATION     CENTERLOCATION,
                'Unknown'        CENTERORDER,
                NULL             CENTERLINE,
                NULL             CENTERITEM
           FROM ROV_LDS RLC
          WHERE     RLC.NAME NOT IN
                        (SELECT CENTERNAME
                           FROM ROV_CENTER_LDS)
                AND RLC.NAME NOT IN
                        (SELECT TGTNAME
                           FROM ROV_TGT_LDS)
                AND (   RLC.LOCATION LIKE '%CENTER%'
                     OR RLC.LOCATION LIKE '%PK%')),
    RV_UNKNOWN_TGT_LDS
    AS
        (SELECT NULL             PLACENAME,
                NULL             PLACESTATUS,
                NULL             PLACEPLC,
                NULL             PLACERECOVERING,
                NULL             PLACEADDRESS,
                NULL             CENTERNAME,
                NULL             CENTERLOCATION,
                NULL             CENTERORDER,
                NULL             CENTERLINE,
                NULL             CENTERITEM
           FROM ROV_LDS RLC
          WHERE     RLC.NAME NOT IN
                        (SELECT CENTERNAME
                           FROM ROV_CENTER_LDS)
                AND RLC.NAME NOT IN
                        (SELECT TGTNAME
                           FROM ROV_TGT_LDS)
                AND (   RLC.LOCATION LIKE '%TGT%'
                     OR RLC.LOCATION LIKE '%Put%'))
SELECT "PLACENAME","PLACESTATUS","PLACEPLC","PLACERECOVERING","PLACEADDRESS","CENTERNAME","CENTERLOCATION","CENTERORDER","CENTERLINE","CENTERITEM","CENTERQUANTITY","CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY","CENTERERRORQUANTITY","CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY","CENTERSTATUS","CENTERPLCORDER","CENTERPLCERRORCODES","CENTERLOCKS","CENTERINVLOCKS","CENTERINVLINE","TGTNAME","TGTLOCATION","TGTORDER","TGTCARTON","TGTQUANTITY","TGTLOCKS"
  FROM ROV_STATION RS
UNION ALL
SELECT RSLC.PLACENAME,
       RSLC.PLACESTATUS,
       RSLC.PLACEPLC,
       RSLC.PLACERECOVERING,
       RSLC.PLACEADDRESS,
       RSLC.CENTERNAME,
       RSLC.CENTERLOCATION,
       RSLC.CENTERORDER,
       RSLC.CENTERLINE,
       RSLC.CENTERITEM
  FROM ROV_CENTER_LDS  RSLC
       LEFT JOIN ROV_TGT_LDS RTLC
           ON RTLC.TGTORDER = RSLC.CENTERORDER
 WHERE RSLC.CENTERNAME NOT IN
           (SELECT TGTNAME FROM ROV_TGT_LDS)
UNION ALL
SELECT "PLACENAME","PLACESTATUS","PLACEPLC","PLACERECOVERING","PLACEADDRESS","CENTERNAME","CENTERLOCATION","CENTERORDER","CENTERLINE","CENTERITEM","CENTERQUANTITY","CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY","CENTERERRORQUANTITY","CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY","CENTERSTATUS","CENTERPLCORDER","CENTERPLCERRORCODES","CENTERLOCKS","CENTERINVLOCKS","CENTERINVLINE","TGTNAME","TGTLOCATION","TGTORDER","TGTCARTON","TGTQUANTITY","TGTLOCKS"
  FROM RV_UNKNOWN_CENTER_LDS RUSLC
UNION ALL
SELECT "PLACENAME","PLACESTATUS","PLACEPLC","PLACERECOVERING","PLACEADDRESS","CENTERNAME","CENTERLOCATION","CENTERORDER","CENTERLINE","CENTERITEM","CENTERQUANTITY","CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY","CENTERERRORQUANTITY","CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY","CENTERSTATUS","CENTERPLCORDER","CENTERPLCERRORCODES","CENTERLOCKS","CENTERINVLOCKS","CENTERINVLINE","TGTNAME","TGTLOCATION","TGTORDER","TGTCARTON","TGTQUANTITY","TGTLOCKS"
  FROM ROV_TGT_LDS RTLC
 WHERE RTLC.TGTNAME NOT IN
           (SELECT CENTERNAME FROM ROV_CENTER_LDS)
UNION ALL
SELECT "PLACENAME","PLACESTATUS","PLACEPLC","PLACERECOVERING","PLACEADDRESS","CENTERNAME","CENTERLOCATION","CENTERORDER","CENTERLINE","CENTERITEM","CENTERQUANTITY","CENTERORIGINALQUANTITY","CENTERERRORQUANTITY","CENTERCOMPLETEQUANTITY","CENTERSTATUS","CENTERPLCORDER","CENTERPLCERRORCODES","CENTERLOCKS","CENTERINVLOCKS","CENTERINVLINE","TGTNAME","TGTLOCATION","TGTORDER","TGTCARTON","TGTQUANTITY","TGTLOCKS"
  FROM RV_UNKNOWN_TGT_LDS RUTLC;
```

The problems in the Explain query are listed in this image below...[image]

It could be the ListAgg causing the problems but another opinion on how to improve would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the view intended to be queried in its entirety (as the execution plan seems to show happening), or would users normally include a `where` clause? If you need all rows, the plan estimates it will return 645T rows totalling 12E bytes (12 million terabytes). Is that right? If you only want some subset, it may be that the structure of the query requires it to access all the rows and only filter the results at the end, which will not be ideal for this volume of data. By the way, the execution plan shown does not report memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer is estimating the query will process **colossal** numbers of rows. Many operations are expected to return *hundreds of millions to trillions of rows*. Even if these numbers are large over estimates, it's likely the query is doing a huge amount of work.

You need to find a way to reduce how much data the query accesses. One way to do this is to reduce how many times you access each table.

Several tables/subqueries are listed many times in the query. e.g. LD_TRANSPORT_STATUS appears four times; ROV_TGT_LDS is listed six times. Refactoring the statement to access table as few times as possible is likely to help.

Here's a possible optimization for these `ld_transport_status` joins to get you started:

```
left join ( 
  select max (transport_status) transport_status,
         ld_id
  from   ld_transport_status
  where  transport_status >= 1
  group by ld_id
) mdlcts
on mdlcts.ld_id = lc.id
left join ld_transport_status dlcts
on     dlcts.ld_id = mdlcts.ld_id
and dlcts.transport_status = mdlcts.transport_status
```

I read this as "Find the rows with the largest `transport_status` for each `ld_id`".

If this is the case, it should be possible to combine this into one access of `transport_status`:

- A subquery with `max ( transport_status )` as an analytic/window function
- Filtering this to only return the rows where the `transport_status` equals this maximum found.

For example:

```
left join ( 
  select max ( transport_status ) 
           over ( partition by ld_id ) mx_transport_status,
         ld_id,
         transport_status,
         -- other cols 
  from   ld_transport_status
  where  transport_status >= 1
) mdlcts
on   mdlcts.ld_id = lc.id
and  mdlcts.mx_transport_status = mdlcts.transport_status
```

There's a similar subquery that finds the `min ( transport_status )`; this should be similarly rewritten. It's possible you could combine both into one query that filters to the rows that equal the min or max.

I don't understand the query well enough to proposed further improvements; it's likely you'll have to iteratively work on this until performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Others may have more observations, but here's my 2 cents worth:

Your "`with [name] as`" statements must be instantiated *in their entirety* before your top-level query can run against them. They are creating HUGE temporary tables (10's of TB according to your explain plan), *without indexes*, and subsequently require full table scans as they are joined. All of that requires lots of disk i/o, which is always a performance killer.

I would recommend making each of those CTEs into a materialized view, with appropriate indexes (and possibly partitions) to support the top-level joins. That should reduce your optimizer cost substantially and may point you in the direction of other things that could be improved.

Comment: Common table expressions are not always materialized in Oracle. It's up to the optimizer to decide whether to turn the CTE into a temp table or to merge it into other parts of the query. That's why Oracle has the (undocumented but popular) hints `MATERIALIZE` and `INLINE`.

Comment: Thank you pmdba, I do agree with you comments they make a lot of sense. So I will need to CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mat_vw AS SELECT... prior to the CREATE VIEW and then call the MATERIALIZED VIEW within the ROV_STATION AS and ROV_LDS AS by using SELECT * FROM mat_vw. I will need to discuss the indices with the DBA's but it should make a lot of difference. Can you please let me know if I have missed anything. Thanks

Comment: @user616076 work with your DBAs. They should know your particular system and be able to help with further tuning.

Comment: @JonHeller True, but when I see 10s of TB of data being processed in each case (assuming the explain plan metrics are correct), I suspect that isn't all happening in main memory. :-)

Comment: Agree CTEs don't have to be materialised, although in this case the plan does show TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION / LOAD AS SELECT for the 6 CTEs resulting in internal temp tables names beginning SYS_TEMP_0FD9E2, some of which are indeed huge. `ROV_STATION` (`8F`) seems to have 1 row assuming plan estimates are accurate, while `ROV_TGT_LDS` (`92`) is 668M rows and `ROV_LDS` (`90`) is 14G rows. There is one join that the optimiser estimates will return 12P rows. We don't know what hardware the OP has but I'd have to question the business case for a report that returns 12 Exabytes of data.